# Symfony 3.0.1 CMF routing

Tags: routes, symfony, symfony-cmf

first I apologize for my bad english and probably silly question.
I installed a new version of Symfony - 3.0.1 and then tried to install with Composer   symfony-cmf/routing but Command Line allerted me that this is possible only for Symfony versions 2.2 to 2.8.2

Any idea how to solve this? 
Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stable versions of the Symfony CMF routing component are only usable with Symfony 2.x. Some weeks ago, 1.4.0-RC2 was released. This release comes with Symfony 3 support.

Make sure you flag the package to allow installing RC versions:

```
{
    "require": {
        ...
        "symfony-cmf/routing": "~1.4@rc"
    }
}
```

A 1.4 stable release of this package is coming soon.

*(Please note that the CmfRoutingBundle does not work on Symfony 3, support for Symfony 3 is expected mid-2016)*

Comment: current WIP for CmfRoutingBundle Symfony 3 support is https://github.com/symfony-cmf/RoutingBundle/pull/331